# In my web-scraping, some divs don't appear

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape an HTML page with this code :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,
                                    "myclass")))  
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = bs(html, "lxml")
    print(html)
    dynamic_text = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "myclass"})  
except:
       print("Couldnt locate element")
```

The html page is opened but in my IDE console I see the except message. As it seems, the div with the class_name "myclass" isn't found. However, when I inspect the html page that I got I see there the div with that class name.

The div in the HTML :

```
<div role="radio" data-ng-attr-id="{{radioId}}" data-ng-attr-tabindex="{{directToShow === strVm.data.selectedDirectToShow ? '0' : '-1'}}" data-ng-attr-aria-checked="{{directToShow === strVm.data.selectedDirectToShow ? 'true' : 'false'}}" class="trainBasicInfo ng-scope" data-ng-if="directToShow.date == undefined" data-ng-click="strVm.onSelectDirectToShow(directToShow, $event)" data-ng-class="{'active': directToShow === strVm.data.selectedDirectToShow}" id="railRadio_423" tabindex="-1" aria-checked="false">
```

I put in comment the `WebDriverWait` and I saw the output of the print(html) command. In the output of the print I don't see the div, but when I check the inspect of the chrome page that was opened I can see the div.

Comment: Can you send the URL ?

Comment: https://www.rail.co.il/pages/trainsearchresultnew.aspx?FSID=4170&TSID=5000&Date=20190630&Hour=1000&IOT=true&IBA=false&TSP=1561835762832

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which `class` you used, but the class when inspecting with Browser, and the class from source page is not the same : the [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) is modified by JavaScript, after loading the page source code.

Try this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
try:
    elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,
                                    "//div[contains(@class, 'trainBasicInfo ng-scope')]")))  
    # By.XPATH gives more flexibility
    for element in elements: 
        print(element)
except:
       # print("Couldnt locate element")
       raise  # except with no Exception specified is prohibited
```

From `inspect` with Chrom Dev Tools: 
[image]

From `view-source:https://www.rail.co.il/pages/trainsearchresultnew.aspx?FSID=4170&TSID=5000&Date=20190630&Hour=1000&IOT=true&IBA=false&TSP=1561835762832`: 
[image]

The output is, as follows:

```py
30.06.2019 יום א'
00:46
רציף 1
19:12
19:58
רכבת 687
החלפה 19:44
תל אביב - ההגנה - רציף 3
רכבת 425
30.06.2019 יום א'
00:44
רציף 1
19:27
20:11
רכבת 689
החלפה 19:56
תל אביב - ההגנה - רציף 3
רכבת 529
30.06.2019 יום א'
00:42
רציף 1
19:57
20:39
רכבת 691
החלפה 20:26
תל אביב - ההגנה - רציף 3
רכבת 979
30.06.2019 יום א'
00:44
רציף 1
20:27
21:11
רכבת 693
החלפה 20:56
תל אביב - ההגנה - רציף 2
רכבת 531
30.06.2019 יום א'
00:44
רציף 1
21:27
22:11
רכבת 8695
החלפה 21:49
תל אביב - סבידור מרכז - רציף 3
רכבת 533
```

Comment: First of all thanks ! That worked. The class name that I used is: trainBasicInfo ng-scope. II used the By.class_name instead of by.xpath. Any idea why xpath worked and class_name didnt work ?

Comment: The `class name` in the DOM is `trainBasicInfo ng-scope active show-path`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Selenium, you should try this:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"myclass")))

html = driver.page_source
dynamic_text = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div') #this will be a list of all divs on the page, they all will be selenium object
```

Also keep in mind, that some script generated content on the page may not be there, depending on your driver configuration

Comment: The problem isnt in the find_elements but rather in the webdriverwait.. It seems that when selenium opens my chrome browser and I inspect the elements, I can find the div but in the code nothing can find that div..

Comment: If the element you are looking for, loads after the WebDriverWait(), then you wont find it by running your script. What you can try to do is to not close the driver after you script is done, and look what your script can see, by manually inspecting the page.

Comment: I done that , as I said, in the chrome browser that the script opened, I can see the relevant div.. In my script`s print output , I dont see the div..

Comment: Then try to change your WebDriverWait() target from a class to a xpath, 
 WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="element after the div im looking for"]')))

or just remove the WebDriverWait() all together

Comment: it doesnt matter. The driver.page_source doesnt show that div while I can see it in the browser.. This is the issue here..

Comment: most likely that div is a part of some script's dynamic content, and just doesn't exist in the page source

Comment: try finding that exact div with driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//xpath/to/your/div') and checking it's content by element.get_attribute('attribute you need')